# Commerce: Show taxes on checkout

Tags: commerce

I am having problems with a porjectr of mine. Seems the taxes are not showing up until AFTER the order is put through. Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

I would like to have taxes show up at the button right before total. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

i.stack.imgur.com/3hMWC.png

Answer (score 1):

Taxes are dependent on shipping address so adding a tax line item to the cart does not make sense. Try looking at one of the tax rules on /admin/config/workflow/rules/components to see how the tax line item is added to an order. By default, tax line item is added in the pane that comes after a customer has entered her shipping address and before payment is submitted. Adding a tax line item to a cart requires a custom line-item type and a shipping address to be provided for tax calculation.